# Can't load any OS on my thinkpad -- Using drive 0, partition 4, No o/s

Tags: boot, operating-systems, thinkpad

I've tried to install an OS on a Thinkpad X220. But, if I plug a usb stick on it, there is an error message : "Using drive 0, partition 3. No O/S" and I can't do anything else...
And I can't reset my computer from the bios. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

That machine is quite old and comes with an early 80 GB SSD drive.  The SSD drive is likely bad.

https://www.storagereview.com/review/lenovo-thinkpad-x220-review

See if you can load Lenovo Diagnostics on a bootable USB drive and test the drive.

Comment: I can't download Lenovo Diagnostics from an other computer, no?

Comment: Try a third party disk test utility for a bootable USB key. This error (above) almost for sure results from a defective drive.

Comment: I try with gparted, which is booting, that's a great begin